# nested pound signs around variable with nested loop variable

Tags: coldfusion

I have a table in a form with a loop around it that sets an index on all the name fields (form variables) that changes based on user input (user dictates how many tables get built).
Once submitted, I take these variables and create a struct out of it. I know that a query object is already a struct, but I have to have each tables names unique, then put them into a struct which I can then rename to insert into the DB.
My problem is how do I write this correctly and efficiently? I need to have a variable with a nested variable that is my index to make the name unique for each iteration through the loop. I have tried many combinations of pound signs and quotes and can't get it.
If there is a better way to do this I am up for that too!
dot notation

- cfset myStruct#i#=StructNew()>
- cfset myStruct#i#.ID#i#="#form.myVarA#i##"
- cfset myStruct#i#.s1#i#="#form.myVarB#i##"
- cfset myStruct#i#.s2#i#="#form.myVarC#i##"

associated array notation

- cfset myStruct#i#=StructNew()>
- cfset myStruct#i#[ID#i#]="#form.myVarA#i##"
- cfset myStruct#i#[s1#i#]="#form.myVarB#i##"
- cfset myStruct#i#[s2#i#]="#form.myVarC#i##"

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the best reference you'll ever need to understand variables in CFML:

http://www.depressedpress.com/Content/Development/ColdFusion/Guides/Variables/Index.cfm

To answer your question, try this:

```
<cfset myStruct["#i#"] = structNew() />
<cfset myStruct["#i#"]["ID#i#"] = form["myVarA#i#"] />
<cfset myStruct["#i#"]["s1#i#"] = form["myVarB#i#"] />
```

This should give you:

myStruct.1.id1 = form.myvarA1
myStruct.1.s11 = form.myvarB1

Comment: Huge thanks - works like a charm and a great reference as well!

Comment: No need for the "s and #s in the first part. <cfset myStruct[i] ...>

Comment: You can also concatenate as string (which I find more readable): form["myVarA" & i]

Comment: @Patrick - true, but I didn't want to change approach half way.